# django moving a OneToOneField to a ForeignKey while keeping data

Tags: python, django

I just took over a Django project from another developer and am trying to understand what he did.

If someone could let me know if I understand correctly and point me in the right direction that would be great.

At the moment the models look like this (simplified):

```
class Address:
    street_name=models.CharField()

class Provider:
    address=models.OneToOneField(Address)

class User:
    address=models.OneToOneField(Address)
```

But this means that each Address is unique, so no people living in the same house.

For me (coming from a Symfony framework) I would add a OneToMany field in Provider and User but in Django that is a ForeignKey in Address.

```
class Address:
    street_name=models.CharField()
    provider=models.ForeignKey(Provider)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)

class Provider:

class User:
```

But obviously I would like to keep the address information that is in the database.

How should I do that? Should I look into Data migration (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

Comment: Its something you'd need to know the business decision behind really

Comment: No, it's ForeignKeys on Provider and User. Your proposal would still only allow a single provider/user per address, but multiple addresses per provider/user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the `OneToOneField`s to `ForeignKey`s, then you will be able to select the same address for multiple users and providers.

```
class Provider:
    address=models.ForeignKey(Address)

class User:
    address=models.ForeignKey(Address)
```

You will need to create a migration and run it to drop the unique constraints in the database. A data migration shouldn't be required.

Comment: Exactly this. I did this a few months ago without any issue. Just make sure you check your code to ensure you don't count on the unique constraint to prevent wrong data

Comment: To expand on @Exelian's comment, you'll still be able to do `user.address`, but `address.user` will no longer work, because each address can have multiple users.

Comment: Thanks this works!
Hadn't tried it this way around...
I understood from the Django documentation that the ForeignKey should be in the "Many" Class. Did I understand that wrong?

Comment: Having a foreign key `User.address` means that each user has one address (and each address can have zero or more users). As Daniel says in his comment, a foreign key `Address.user` means that each address has one user, (and each user can have zero or more addresses).